# How to fix Ticks in Gauges?

Tags: formatting, visualization, gui-construction

Ticks is an option for Gauges. I fail, however, to apply custom Ticks to Gauges. For instance, compare these two:

```
 {ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, Ticks -> Automatic], 
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, Ticks -> {0, 50, 100}]}
```

What you see is this:

[image]

*No difference!*

I also tried with the Horizontal- and VerticalGauge with the same success.

*Do you know a workaround?*

EDIT 11.07.13: I have seen the answers to my question. They all are good and fascinating, and in another case I will certainly use them. They do not answer my question though. For this reason I would like to give some more explanation of what I am really after. I will give it within an example of a different problem, where it is easy to obtain such a result.

So let us consider two simple plots. First is this

```
Plot[x, {x, -0.3, 0.3}, ImageSize -> 250]
```

second is this:

```
 Plot[x, {x, -0.3, 0.3}, Ticks -> {{0, 3/16, 1/4}, Automatic}, 
 ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Here you can see it. The y axis in both plots is automatic - do not look at it. The x axis of the first plot is automatic for comparison, while the x axis of the second plot is what I am after. I would like to achieve the same on the ThermometerGauge, if possible by easy means. The easy means are here important, since looking at programs below I feel that it is easier to draw such a Gauge from scratch. For example, like this:

```
  thermo[x_] := Show[{
   Graphics3D[{Text[Style["-0.3", 12], {-0.15, 0, -0.3}], 
     Text[Style["0", 12], {-0.15, 0, 0}],
     Text[Style["3/16", 12], {0.14, 0, 3/16}] , 
     Text[Style["1/4", 12], {0.15, 0, 0.25}] , 
     Text[Style["0.3", 12], {-0.13, 0, 0.3}]}, 
    ViewPoint -> {0, -1.5, 0}, Boxed -> False, 
    ImageSize -> {120, 300}],
   Graphics3D[{LightBlue, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.5], 
     Sphere[{0, 0, -0.4}, 0.11]}],
   Graphics3D[{Red, Specularity[White, 20], 
     Sphere[{0, 0, -0.4}, 0.1]}],
   Graphics3D[{LightBlue, Opacity[0.5], 
     Tube[{{0, 0, -0.4}, {0, 0, 0.35}}, 0.05]}],
   Graphics3D[{Red, Specularity[White, 20], 
     Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.45}, {0, 0, x}}, 0.04]}],

   Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.015], 
     Line[{{-0.07, 0, #}, {-0.09, 0, #}}] & /@ 
      Table[i, {i, -0.3, 0.3, 0.1}]}],
   Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[0.015], 
     Arrow[{{0.09, 0, 3/16}, {0.03, 0, 3/16}}], 
     Arrow[{{0.09, 0, 0.25}, {0.03, 0, 0.25}}]}]
   }]
```

Try it:

```
Manipulate[
 thermo[x], {{x, 0}, -0.3, 0.3}]
```

It looks as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are after, but maybe this? `ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, ScaleDivisions -> 2]`

Comment: @PinguinDirk `ScaleDivisions -> 2`, hmm bug? :)

Comment: weird, indeed, `2` and `3` give the same result...

Comment: @Pinguin Dirk good to know, thank you. But I need really custom ticks. I will write a manipulator with ThermometerGauge instead of slider, with the interval from, say, -0.3 to 0.3 such that there are ticks {0, 1/4, 3/16} only.

Comment: @Kuba: it seems that it is using something like `FindDivisions` to get the ticks, check e.g. `9` vs `10`... Knowing that, it'll be tough exploiting this feature to get really "custom" ticks. Guess another approach is needed.

Comment: So You want to set only a set of custom ticks, not a range? If so, then adapt george2079's solution, You only need to rescale positions. `Scaled[{0,0}]` is reffering **always** to 0 Degree, and `Scaled[{0,1}]` to max temp from `Therm..[x, {0, max}]`

Answer (score 6):

Ticks does not appear to be an option for `ThermometerGauge`. (TicksStyle is.)  You must use `ScaleDivisions` from what I can tell.

Mathematica seems to be making some aesthetic judgment about the request for 3 scale divisions.  It won't divide {0,100}, {0, 99} or {0,90} into 3 divisions but it happily does so for the scales {0, 30} and {0,300}.

```
{ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, ScaleDivisions -> 2],
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, ScaleDivisions -> 3],
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 99}, ScaleDivisions -> 3],
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 90}, ScaleDivisions -> 3],
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 30}, ScaleDivisions -> 3],
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 300}, ScaleDivisions -> 3],
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, ScaleDivisions -> 4],
 ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, ScaleDivisions -> 5]}
```

[image: thermometers]

Comment: I'd suspect: `FindDivisions[{0, 100}, #] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5}` resp `FindDivisions[{0, 300}, #] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5}`, yields exactly these values

Comment: It wants to avoid fractions :)

Comment: @David Carraher Thank you, it is a nice idea. Unfortunately, it does not answer my question. Probably such an answer does not exist.

Comment: Kuba, It's more than fractions. If you try to divide the scale {0,99} into 3, it also balks.

Comment: Alexei, `Ticks` does not appear as an option for `ThermometerGauge`.

Comment: @David Carraher If you evaluate Options[ThermometerGauge], you find Ticks->Automatic in the very end of the output.

Comment: Alexei. Very interesting. I wonder why Ticks not listed online as an option for ThermometerGauge. Also, `AbsoluteOptions[ThermometerGauge[50, {0, 100}, Ticks -> {0, 50, 100}]]` returns, among other things, `Ticks-> {{},{}}, TicksStyle->{}`.

Answer (score 2):

another hack, turn them off and draw manualy..

```
Show[ {
  Graphics[
   { Text[#, {-.1, .01 #}]  , 
     Line[{{-.01, 0.01 #}, {-.065, .01 #}}]}]  &
               /@ Table[33 i , {i, 0, 3}] , 
    Graphics[ Line[{{-.01 , 0.01 #}, {-.065/2, .01 #}}] ] &
               /@ Table[3 i , {i, 0, 33}],
    ThermometerGauge[33, {1, 99}, ScaleDivisions -> 0]}]
```

[image]

note as a quick hack i didn't work out the exact scaling, but it looks right.

edit: more general version.

```
myguage[val_, {min_, max_}, nmaj_] := 
 Module[{tic, x0 = -.01, x1 = -.065},
  tic[y_, x0_, x1_] := Line[{{x0, y}, {x1, y}}];
  Show[{Graphics@{
      {
         Text[Round[# (max - min)/(nmaj - 1) + min, .01],
                 {1.8 x1, (#/(nmaj - 1))}],
         tic[(#/  (nmaj - 1)), x0, x1]
         } & /@ Range[0, nmaj - 1] ,
      ,
      tic[(#/(5  (nmaj - 1))), x0, x1/2] & /@ Range[0, 5  (nmaj - 1)]}
    ,
    ThermometerGauge[val, {min, max}, ScaleDivisions -> 0]}]]
myguage[72, {32, 212}, 7]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any undocumented option but here is a solution:

**static `ThermometerGauge`**:

```
ticks[{s_, k_}, {p_, q_}] := ReplaceAll[#, {
 {{_, Scaled[{-0.1, _}, _]} ..} :> ({{0., #}, Scaled[{-0.1, 0}, {0., #}]
                                    } & /@Table[i/k, {i, s, k, (k - s)/p}]),
 {{_, Scaled[{-0.065, _}, _]} ..} :> ({{0., #}, Scaled[{-0.065, 0}, {0., #}]
                                      } & /@Table[i/k, {i, s, k, (k - s)/(p q)}]),
 {Text[___] ..} :> (Text[Round[k #, .1], Offset[{-3., 0.}, Scaled[{-0.1, 0.}, {0., #}]], 
                         {1, 0.}, {1, 0}] & /@ Table[i/k, {i, s, k, (k - s)/p}])
 }] &;

ThermometerGauge[33, {1, 99}] // ticks[{0, 99}, {3, 4}]
```

[image]

**dynamic `ThermometerGauge`**:

```
 ticks2[{s_, k_}, {p_, q_}] := ReplaceAll[#, {
 {{_, Scaled[{-0.1, _}, _]} ..} :> ({{0., #}, Scaled[{-0.1, 0}, {0., #}]
                                    } & /@Table[i/k, {i, s, k, (k - s)/p}]),
 {{_, Scaled[{-0.065, _}, _]} ..} :> ({{0., #}, Scaled[{-0.065, 0}, {0., #}]
                                      } & /@ Table[i/k, {i, s, k, (k - s)/(p q)}]),
 {Inset[___] ..} :> (Inset[Round[# k,.1], Offset[{-3., 0.}, Scaled[{-0.1, 0.}, 
                           {0., #}]], {1, 0.}, Automatic, {1, 0}
                          ] & /@ Table[i/k, {i, s, k, (k - s)/p}])
 }] &;

ThermometerGauge[Dynamic@x, {13, 123}] // ticks2[{13, 123}, {5, 5}]
```

[image]