# How can you set the scale ticks in a Gauge?

Tags: gui-construction

I can't seem to access a `FrameTicks` type option for setting the values of frame ticks on the axes of a `Gauge`.  Below is an example, how can I change the ticks from seconds to minutes:

```
Clear[Countdown];
Countdown[sec_] := (RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
  $countdownTimer = sec;
      RunScheduledTask[$countdownTimer--, {1, sec}];
  RunScheduledTask[EmitSound[Play[Sin[1000 t^2], {t, 0, 1}]]; 
   CreateDialog[{TextCell[
      ToString[sec] <> " seconds complete :) Time up"], 
     DefaultButton[]}], {sec}];
  Dynamic@
   HorizontalGauge[$countdownTimer, {sec, 
         0}, GaugeStyle -> Hue[Rescale[$countdownTimer, {0, sec}, {0, 0.3}]], 
    GaugeMarkers -> "GlassRectangle", ScaleDivisions -> 10, 
    ImageSize -> {700}, ScalePadding -> None, 
    Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: By the way, the simplest workaround is `orizontalGauge[$countdownTimer/60, {sec, 0}/60, ...]`

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/how-to-fix-ticks-in-gauges

Comment: If you make `Frame->True` you'll see that the gauge ticks/markers are not part of the frame. A horizontal gauge lies along an x axis but those ticks are not used either. Instead the tick marks you see are `Inset`s.

Comment: @ybeltukov good point, @MikeHoneychurch, thanks, could `DynamicModule[]` be used here to better enclose things?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to scale your gauge to display timer value in seconds by dividing by 60. Here is a 3-minute gauge.

```
With[{val = 100, sec = 180}, 
  HorizontalGauge[val/60, {sec/60, 0}, 
    GaugeStyle -> Hue[Rescale[val, {0, sec}, {0, 0.3}]], 
    GaugeMarkers -> "GlassRectangle",
    ScaleDivisions -> 3,
    ImageSize -> 500,
    ScalePadding -> None,
    Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

[image: gauge]